Быстрая сортировка по убыванию по первому элементу. Как должны идти правый и левый маркеры?
Если для сортировки по возрастанию массива выбирается первый элемент, левый маркер указывает на элементы больше равны пилоту а правый на элементы меньше равны пивоту,то как быть с сортировкой на убывание? вот есть массив 23 33 - левый указывает на 33 и должен искать элемент меньше за 23 но дальше массив заканчивается. Как в таком случае действовать ?

Какую реализацию partition вы имеете в виду? Вот из вики схема Хоара, на убывание нужно поменять знаки сравнения в двух while. Для вашего набора индексы не сдвинутся, произойдёт обмен, получится 33 23
